# Trigger shell command by scanning an NFC / RFID sticker?

Tags: shell-script

I just saw [this hack](https://hackaday.com/2019/01/06/the-jookbox-is-a-post-modern-jukebox/) which made me really want to do something similar.

At home I have two small kids, a TV connected to a linux pc which has a ton of kids's videos. I'm thinking I should be able to kludge together ...something... so that I could give my kids a little box of "movie covers" that, when scanned, start the corresponding media (basically firing off a VLC command).

But I don't have a reader for my pc, and I don't actually know how to pick a good one (or whether I should use NFC or RFID), and how I would make it "always available" for scanning something.

What I can find online requires running a command before each scan, or is targeted at mobile OS'es, or is simply too scant on details.

Edit: Ease of implementation is valuable, but so is ease of use for small kids. I thought about having a mag stripe reader, but of course then it becomes a bit more cumbersome to create new cards.

Any guidance?

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/Yimbo/attendance for NFC example (Python)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (and have done before) is to get a cheap/second hand barcode scanner and use that. 1D scanners scan normal barcodes (just a few characters), 2D scanners can handle QR codes (a lot of characters).

The benefit of barcode scanners is that they behave like a keyboard. Every time you scan a barcode, it will "type" the scanned characters and add a newline. When you have that it is trivial to write a script in any language to launch a movie. (for example bash and mplayer)

QR codes are easy to generate using online tools or qrencode (https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/). You could even encode the filenames into the QR code and just make the video player open whatever gets scanned.

Might not be as fancy as NFC, but it is a lot easier and a lot cheaper ;)

Comment: Thank you, Johan. Ease is very valuable in my current situation (in life, not tech). I was mostly thinking about how the kids would use the thing when it's "in production", and thought that a fixed, passive sensor would be most convenient.